# Log4j.properties in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, log4j

How to load Custom Log4j.properties file in Spring boot

My code in application.properties is here

```
logging.file=E:/Apps_Tek/apps-webservices-log/apps-webservices.log
logging.level.*=INFO
logging.config=log4j.properties
```

My code in log4j.properties is here

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,ConsoleAppender,FileAppender

log4j.appender.ConsoleAppender=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.ConsoleAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ConsoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%-7p %d [%t] %c [%X{userName}] [%X{accessToken}] - %m%n

log4j.appender.FileAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FileAppender.File=E:/Apps_Tek/apps-webservices-log/apps-webservices.log
log4j.appender.FileAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FileAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%-7p %d [%t] %c [%X{userName}] [%X{accessToken}] - %m%n
```

But i am not getting any expected output i.e., spring boot is not loading log4j.properties file. Spring boot is having its own default logging.

log4j.properties file is in `src/main/resources`

My question is how to map log4j.properties file with logging.config property in application.properties if it is in src/main/resources.

Please suggest all the required changes.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 50):

If you want spring boot to use log4j instead of its own default logging (logback) then you have to exclude default logging and include the log4j dependency for spring boot in your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

that way is going to look for your log4j.properties file located in `src/main/resources`.

Also if you wish to use properties defined in you application.properties inside the log4j.properties file

> for example, you want to have `log.file.path` defined in your `application.properties` and use it on `log4j.properties`

Then you have to define filtering inside your `pom.xml:`

```
<filters>
    <filter>src/main/resources/application.properties</filter>
</filters>
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>log4j.properties</include>
        </includes>         
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

That way you can have:

```
log4j.appender.file.File=${log.file.path}/${project.artifactId}.log
```

in your `log4j.properties` file

Comment: I added code as per your suggestion and get error , `For artifact {org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j:null:jar}: The version cannot be empty. (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources:default-resources:process-resources)`  which is [another SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38011232/maven-for-artifact-the-version-cannot-be-empty)

Comment: <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
to make it work for me I needed to add a version number, 
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.8.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: i have lot of `spring-boot-starter-*`, but nothing that match the whole thing

Comment: spring-boot-starter-log4j2 is working with boot 1.5.x without explicit version

Answer (score 8):

To exclude default logging and include the log4j dependency for spring boot in your pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

if you wish to use log4j properties defined in you application.properties inside the log4j.properties file need to add below property in application.properties file.

logging.config = src/main/resources/log4j2.properties

Then spring boot will read the properties from  log4j2.properties file

In log4j2.properties file add the below properties

```
name=PropertiesConfig
appenders = console, file

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = ConsoleAppender
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{MM:dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] [%level] [%logger{36}] - %msg%n

appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = FileAppender
appender.file.fileName=/home/ubuntu/application.log
appender.file.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern= %d{MM:dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] [%level] [%logger{36}] - %msg%n

loggers=file
logger.file.name=com.project
logger.file.level = debug
logger.file.appenderRefs = file
logger.file.appenderRef.file.ref = FileAppender

rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = ConsoleAppender
```

Is there any other work around which doesnot require to specify 
'logging.config = src/main/resources/log4j2.properties' inside application.properties file..?

**Note : Spring boot version  i am using is 2.1.3.RELEASE**

**Reference : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html**

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your pom.xml file is not set up to include the correct log4j dependency.  If you do that it should automatically work.  See their example at [spring-boot-sample-actuator-log4j](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-actuator-log4j).  Their project includes the artifact spring-boot-starter-log4j which should then allow your log4j.properties to be picked up from the current src/main/resources location and you should no longer need the logging.* entries in your properties. It may also be possible that you need to exclude their spring-boot-starter-logging as I see they are doing that as well. If this does not seem to resolve it please post your POM file in a location I can see it.  Please let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Link is not found, getting 404.

Comment: Looks like they got rid of that one.  This appears to be the latest https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-actuator-log4j2  The answer above is better anyhow since they explain how to do the exclusion.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone faces the same problem, I did not have the *spring-boot-starter* dependency so I had to add the  to the *spring-boot-starter-web* dependency, this is how it looked:

```
<!-- Spring Boot Starter Web -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <!-- Excluding logback dependencies to use l4j2 -->
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Then you add the Log4j2 Dependency:

```
<!-- Add Log4j2 Dependency -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Your log4j2.properties file will be used for logging configurations from now on.