# Maven - for artifact the version cannot be empty

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

**Problem:** I am using maven and suddenly got some errors:

```
For artifact {org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:null:jar}: The version cannot be empty. (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources:default-resources:process-resources)

org.apache.maven.artifact.InvalidArtifactRTException: For artifact {org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:null:jar}: The version cannot be empty.
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.DefaultArtifact.validateIdentity(DefaultArtifact.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.DefaultArtifact.<init>(DefaultArtifact.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.factory.DefaultArtifactFactory.createArtifact(DefaultArtifactFactory.java:157)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.factory.DefaultArtifactFactory.createDependencyArtifact(DefaultArtifactFactory.java:57)
    at org.apache.maven.project.artifact.MavenMetadataSource.createDependencyArtifact(MavenMetadataSource.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.project.artifact.MavenMetadataSource.createArtifacts(MavenMetadataSource.java:503)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultProjectArtifactFactory.createArtifacts(DefaultProjectArtifactFactory.java:50)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:119)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved(MojoExecutor.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1362)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1360)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.build(MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.build(MavenBuilderImpl.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

So I have added the artifact version `<version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>` to spring-boot-starter-data-jpa. Unfortunately I still get the same issue. I have even cleanded the cache of maven. 
`maven -> update` project did not help
and `project -> clean` did neither help

**Question:** What else could I have done wrong?

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>SpringDataDemo</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringDataDemo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>org.jboss.repository.releases</id>
            <name>JBoss Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.192</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


</project>
```

Eclipse marks weird lines red if it really is an issue of version numbers:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to inherit from Spring Boot's parent POM:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

This parent POM declares lots of dependency versions for artifacts you might use on your projects, that way you don't need to specify it yourself.

From the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html#using-boot-dependency-management):

> Each release of Spring Boot provides a curated list of dependencies it
>   supports. In practice, you do not need to provide a version for any of
>   these dependencies in your build configuration as Spring Boot is
>   managing that for you. When you upgrade Spring Boot itself, these
>   dependencies will be upgraded as well in a consistent way.

**See also:**

- [Getting Started - Building an Application with Spring Boot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/)

Comment: In order to get this to work, I had to upgrade my version of Maven.  I had 3.2.3 and I was getting the OP's error.  I just downloaded 3.3.9 and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The version is missing in the following plugin declaration:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
```

Just add the version:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have added the version to plugin declaration. unfortunately the error did not disappear. I have even  made a maven -> update project again. Have you another idea what I could have done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

We need to add the version in parent pom.xml if not in child pom.xml

```
- Parent Module
|-pom.xml
|-Child
    |-pom.xml
```

Parent pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Child pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

My projects normally are either directly or via an other parent derived from `spring-boot-starter-parent`.

Sometimes I've the problem that my eclipse does not download all source files, although I've checked the `Download artifact Sources` field.

To get the missing source files, I then do run the related command manually:

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse -DdownloadSources=true
```

Only if I run this command (and only in some projects) I run into the above mentioned problem (I've no problem when running a "normal" maven command, e.g. `mvn package`).

To solve the issue I've had to add the following block into my `pom.xml`:

```
...
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
      <scope>import</scope>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-data-jpa.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
...
```

The block can be removed afterwards.

The correct `spring-boot.version` depends on your installation. I'm not sure if the `spring-data-jpa.version` is always the same as the `spring-boot.version` (At the time of this writing and in the version I use, they are the same).

If you are not sure, you can find the correct version by adding also the [spring-boot-dependencies](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies) to your `pom.xml` there you find the used version of the [spring-data-bom](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-bom), where you finally find the correct version of the `spring-data-jpa.version`.