# Spring boot: How to pass variable from application-env.properties to another properties file?

Tags: logging, spring-boot, log4j

I have application-local.properties and application-dev.properties in spring boot with following value:
`logging.level.file=INFO`

And in another property file, log4j.properties, I want to get the above value based on my running environment.  I tried to use
 `${logging.level.file}`
, but I fail to get it (empty string).

How should I do it?

Comment: Can you elaborate why exactly you need to do this? What is the final goal? There might be better ways if you could tell this.

Comment: My goal is to set different log level for different environment, for example, DEBUG for local env and INFO for dev env.

Answer (score 0):

This is not so easy. By default, Spring-Boot comes with Logback configuration. However, there is a possibility to activate log4j too, which is discussed in the following thread: [Log4j.properties in Spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29225777/log4j-properties-in-spring-boot).