# Log4j logs to file

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j

I am trying to print simple Log4j logs to an external file implementation with Spring.

**Project Structure -**
[image]

Here's my code -

**1. pom.xml -**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

**2. Controller -**

```
package hello;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GreetingController.class);

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
        logger.info("Hello");
        logger.debug("Hello");
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                            String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

**3. DTO -**

```
 package hello;

    public class Greeting {

        private final long id;
        private final String content;

        public Greeting(long id, String content) {
            this.id = id;
            this.content = content;
        }

        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getContent() {
            return content;
        }
    }
```

**4. Application main class -**

```
    package hello;

    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

    @SpringBootApplication
    public class Application {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        }
    }
```

**5. log4j.properties file -**

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file
log4j.logger.org.springframework=WARN
log4j.logger.hello=DEBUG
# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

log4j.appender.file.File=/home/aniruddha/logigng.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

**I am not able to print logs to the specified location -** `/home/aniruddha/logigng.log`

Comment: Also rather than rely on where you place the log4j.properties, set `log4j.configuration=file:/pathToProject/src/main/resources` in spring's vm options

Comment: i have servlet project and i place this file main/resources, but unable to write logs into file what i have to do

Answer (score 0):

add these property and try it

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework=WARN
log4j.logger.com.test=DEBUG   //com.test is base package, use your base package
```

Comment: tried it, didn't work, updated the question with yr suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Log4j properties in Spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29225777/log4j-properties-in-spring-boot).

Simple exclude default logging and add spring boot log4j dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Yes, it is. But without `exclusions` of  `spring-boot-starter-logging` and add spring boot log4j dependency is not going to look for your log4j.properties