# How to check logging implementation details in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging

I am using `Spring boot`.

I want to check which logging implementation is printing the message - I know with `Spring boot` default is Logback, and I have excluded it as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29225777/log4j-properties-in-spring-boot) post so mostly Logback will not be printing the messages, but I want to show it as a proof that Logback implementation is not printing and probably `Log4j` is printing.

Basically I need an API which I can call and I can get the details of which is the logging implementation, the way we can know `Java` version etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can enforce Spring Boot to use a certain implementation by setting this property:

```
org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystem
```

with any of:

- org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem
- org.springframework.boot.logging.log4j2.Log4J2LoggingSystem
- org.springframework.boot.logging.java.JavaLoggingSystem
- none (to swith off completely)

This explicit configuration would be your proof.

Comment: So, it means if I print `org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystem` value then it would tell my logging implementation?

Comment: I printed and it print NULL as of now... then how can I be sure that once I set this it would use that implementation.... my expectation was that currenlty it should have printed something

Comment: You just set that in your application.properties and Spring uses that implementation explicitly

Answer (score 1):

To check configuration you can install spring actuator framework. Through web endpoints all config params can be queried.

Comment: I tried this approach, but actuator framework don't show default logging implementation framework name (because org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystem is null ? )