# How can I use a property defined in a ".properties" file in my "log4j2.json"?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, log4j, log4j2

I have an application built using the **Spring Framework** and written in **Java**.

I am using the '`log4j`' library for logging and have already defined a property, `fr.xyz.pathLog = mypath`, in my 'dev.properties' file that specifies the file path for my log files.

I would like to use this property in my '`log4j2.json`' configuration file to specify the file path for my log files.

However, when I try to use the property in the '`log4j2.json`', it does not seem to be recognized.

Is there a way to use properties defined in my '`dev.properties`' file in my '`log4j2.json`' configuration file ?

I tried using the '`${fr.xyz.path}`' syntax in the '`log4j2.json`' to specify the file path for my log files, but the property was not recognized when I ran the application.

I expected the property to be recognized and used in the configuration, but this did not happen.

Comment: JSON files are not appropriate for placing env variables, you can use log4j.properties file instead.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29225777/log4j-properties-in-spring-boot

Comment: Did you try the [Spring Lookup](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-spring-boot/index.html)?